# Turning "1 h 19 min" to "1h 19m"

Tags: php, replace

I have strings containing the runtime of movies:

```
1 h 19 min
```

Now I'd like it to look like this:

```
1h 19m
```

I know this should be actually pretty easy but I just don't manage to find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried to *code* a solution?

Comment: from which php function you are getting that string

Comment: Does it always look like `xx h yy min` though? Could it have seconds too?

Answer (score 6):

```
$str = str_replace(array(' h', ' min'), array('h', 'm'), $str);
```

Comment: I'm always amazed by the number of people who don't know about arrays in functions like this – definitely the 'right' way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

```
$runtime="1 h 19 min";
$runtime=str_replace(" h","h",$runtime);
$runtime=str_replace(" min","m",$runtime);
```

Comment: or `$runtime=str_replace(array(" h"," min"),array("h","m"),$runtime);
`

Answer (score 4):

You can remove all spaces between a digit and a non-digit with a regular expression:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\d) *(?=\D)/', '', $str);
```

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/7xtYx).

**Update:** Unfortunately this does not turn "min" into "m", which I didn't actually notice is desired.

In light of this, a `str_replace` solution with arrays such as [bsdnoobz's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11010917/50079) is really the only sane way to go here. But just for the fun of it:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\d) *(\D)\S*/', '$1', $str);
```

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/d5uIL).

Comment: Ooh, so close, but it doesn't turn `min` into `m` :-)

Comment: u can try str_replcae to turn it then ;)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Never give up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way

`$runtime = "1 h 19 min";`

$runtime = str_replace(" h", "h", $runtime);

$runtime = str_replace(" min", "min", $runtime);